# Create muc room programmatically

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I need to create multi user chat room from my module. I try to use mod_muc:create/5 -

```
mod_muc:create_room("conference.localhost", "testroom", "testuser@localhost", "testuser", default).
```

But when i run client and login, nothing happens. The room doesn't create.

How can i correctly create muc room from my module code? And where i can find in ejabberd mod_muc source code where create_room/5 executes?

Thank you.

Comment: Where exactly you're putting that code ?

Comment: @0xAX did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The ejabberd mod_muc source is under `src/mod_muc` in the ejabberd source code, see: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/tree/master/src/mod_muc. Nothing looks wrong with your example code, you may also need to call `mod_muc_room:start/7` after creation.

I would recommend using `ejabberdctl debug` on a developemnt ejabberd server & try these functions directly.